# Date Comparison for to do list in php

Tags: php, date

iam maintaining the TODO list, i have two dates start date, end date, start date in the form of

```
$startdate='2014-03-25 07:01:33';
$enddate='2014-03-26 07:01:33';
$currentdays= date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('-10 days'));
echo strtotime($currentdays)."----------"."<br/>";
echo strtotime($date2)."------------"; 
if($date2>$currentdays){
    echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
        }
```

iam using api for this to get data, i want a tasks that was completed in last ten days from current date of now,how could i compare two dates from end dates to till now, i want ot compare end date with today date,Help me in this regards

Comment: you want to compare 2 dates is right ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert everything to timestamp integer and compare them:

```
$enddate=strtotime('2014-03-26 07:01:33');
$dayLimit = strtotime('-10 days');
if($enddate>$dayLimit){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Yes i want to compare two dates, one is enddate and other current date of last ten days with end-day